# How to determine the size of a table occupied by a set or records/rows in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a requirement to find the size/space occupied in a table by the result set of a query (few rows returned by the query).

Example: the table has 1000 records but the select query returns 150 records. I'm basically interested in knowing the space occupied by those 150 records in the table. How do I find out?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What have you tried or researched so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and try including a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

This is by no means exact, but you can get the average of a row, and use that in your calculation.

```
select AVG_ROW_LEN
from user_tables
where table_name = <whatever>
```